# Stomp WebSocket Client for a Spring based broker built in Java is failing

Tags: c#, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a Websocket Stomp server built in Java (Spring based). My JavaScript client is able to talk to the server using Stomp over Web Socket - no issues.

I'm trying to use the WebSocket4Net library to build the C# client. Can anyone please tell me how can I build the Stomp message frames in bytes[] and send them to the server?

In the `OnOpen()` method, I'm doing the following:

```
String stompMsg = "CONNECT\n";
stompMsg += "accept-version:1.1,1.2\n\n";
stompMsg += "^@";

Byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stompMsg);
websocketObj.Send(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
```

I get the following message from server:

> Failed to parse BinaryMessage payload - java.nio.HeapByteBuffer. 
>   Sending STOMP ERROR to client.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class [org.springframework.web.socket.BinaryMessage] must be an instance of class org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339)
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:319)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:307)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:55)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:71)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleBinaryMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$100(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$4.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$4.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageBinary(WsFrameBase.java:549)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataBinary(WsFrameBase.java:514)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:274)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:116)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:54)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:192)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:178)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:92)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:601)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Can anyone please suggest if you have successfully created / used any C# client library with a spring based STOMP over Web Socket server?

Comment: Does your `^@` mean `new byte[0]`? Everything other looks good. The sample from our tests: `CONNECT\naccept-version:1.2\nhost:github.org\n\n0`

Comment: Thank you, yes I guess I made a mistake there. I changed it now per the example from your tests. However my server still responds with the same message. I also added a little more about the stack trace from the server logs.

Comment: Ah! I see now. Yes, Spring STOMP supports just only `TextMessage`. Can you do the same with that `websocketObj`, but send `TextMessage` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Artem - Thank you SO much. The \0 indeed did the trick.

```
websocket.Send("SUBSCRIBE\nid:sub-0\ndestination:/topic/mytopic\n\n\0");
```